# react-icheck: css-loader fails with error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'minimal/minimal@2x.png'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, icheck, css-loader

I am trying to use this front-end library [react-icheck](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-icheck)  (a port of the [icheck.js](https://github.com/fronteed/icheck) jquery plugin into react) into my react application setup with webpack 2. This is the error I get when I run **npm start**:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'minimal/minimal@2x.png' in '_my_project_directory_\node_modules\icheck\skins'.
```

This is the way I import icheck components in one of my files:

```
require('icheck/skins/all.css');
import {Checkbox, Radio} from 'react-icheck';
```

**minimal/minimal@2x.png** is an image file referenced in the **all.css** I am importing. (relative path)

I have made some research over the internet and found out that it seems that the css-loader and postcss-loader break when the path is relative. Could some one point me to the right direction as to how I could solve this problem? Here I dump the content of my webpack file:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var resolve = path.resolve;

// variables
var isProduction = process.argv.indexOf('-p') >= 0;
var sourcePath = path.join(__dirname, './src');
var outPath = path.join(__dirname, './dist');

// plugins
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  context: sourcePath,
  entry: {
    main: './index.tsx',
    vendor: [
      'react',
      'react-dom',
      'react-redux',
      'react-router',
      'redux'
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: outPath,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  target: 'web',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.tsx'],
    // Fix webpack's default behavior to not load packages with jsnext:main module
    // https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11677
    mainFields: ['main']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      // .ts, .tsx
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: isProduction
          ? 'awesome-typescript-loader?module=es6'
          : [
            //'react-hot-loader',
            'awesome-typescript-loader'
          ]
      },
      // .jsx
      {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loaders: ['react-hot-loader', 'babel-loader'],
                include: sourcePath
       },
      // css
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              query: {
                modules: true,
                sourceMap: !isProduction,
                importLoaders: 1,
                localIdentName: '[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
              }
            },
            {
              loader: 'postcss-loader'
            }
          ]
        })
      },
      // static assets
      { test: /\.html$/, use: 'html-loader' },
      { test: /\.png$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=10000' },
      { test: /\.jpg$/, use: 'file-loader' },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      options: {
        context: sourcePath,
        postcss: [
          require('postcss-import')({ addDependencyTo: webpack }),
          require('postcss-url')(),
          require('postcss-cssnext')(),
          require('postcss-reporter')(),
          require('postcss-browser-reporter')({ disabled: isProduction }),
        ]
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      filename: 'vendor.bundle.js',
      minChunks: Infinity
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: 'styles.css',
      disable: !isProduction
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'index.html'
    })
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: sourcePath,
    hot: true,    
    stats: {
      warnings: false
    },
  },
  node: {
    // workaround for webpack-dev-server issue
    // https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/60#issuecomment-103411179
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty'
  }
};
```

Comment: This is what I just read in the home page of the css-loader on github:

In addition to that relative paths are buggy and you need to use an absolute public path which include the server URL.

It looks like it is a bug from their part. Does that mean that I should go through all my .css files in the node_modules and make any relative path referenced absolute?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it finally by using another loader **resolve-url-loader** and then by requiring my style files in this way:

```
require('!css-loader!resolve-url-loader!icheck/skins/all.css');
```